# Converting all input to uppercase

Tags: java, swing, uppercase

In a Java Swing application, is there a simple way to convert all input to uppercase?

By all input I mean all input in every field of every object everywhere in the application.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why in heaven's name would you want to? :-)

Comment: Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase())... then answer #1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A complete working example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class UpperCasedTextFieldTester extends JFrame {
    /** */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4767854098431909437L;

    public UpperCasedTextFieldTester(){
        setSize(200, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        DocumentFilter filter = new UppercaseDocumentFilter();

        JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
        firstName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        ((AbstractDocument) firstName.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);

        JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
        lastName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));
        ((AbstractDocument) lastName.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);

        add(firstName);
        add(lastName);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new UpperCasedTextFieldTester().setVisible(true);
    }

}

class UppercaseDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
            String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {

        fb.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
    }

    public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
            String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {

        fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
    }
}
```

Comment: your answer has been flagged as a low quality answer. please provide some explanations.

Comment: *"`DocumentFilter`"*  Nice one...  :)

Comment: @KickButtowski  There's a certain eloquence to 'let the code do the talking'. Well.. code, the [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) and the [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

Comment: Ooh, but slight tweak `JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
        firstName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 20));` should better be something like `JTextField firstName = new JTextField(20); // suggest a width in columns!`  See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: Thank you! Thank you!
I am new to Java, so I'm learning new things every day! Now I am beginning to understand DocumentFilters!

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving the input as a string, you could always do `string.toUppercase()` method.